# IMPORTXML and XPath in Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, google-sheets

I have a question how to get pages quantity from here
One of the problems is that I never know how many spans will be in every page with book - here we have just 3, and "pages" span is number [2] here in the list but it can be any number so I cant just get it by  using `//p[@class='book']//text()[2]`

I need to extract "300" using Google spreadsheets IMPORTXML function

```
<p class="book">
<span>condition: <b>good</b></span>
<br>
<span>pages: <b>300</b></span>
<br>
<span>color: <b>red</b></span>
<br>
</p>
```

I tried adding

```
[contains('pages: ')]
```

but no success here

Any suggestions?

p.s. `//p[@class='book']//text()` by itself
returns

```
condition:
good
pages: 
300
color:
red
```

Answer (score 2):

So you look for a **span** that start with **'pages:'** and than take a value from it.

```
//p[@class='book']/span[starts-with(., 'pages:')]/b/text()
```